# Close window when graphics.py object has reached the edge of window

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

Referring to [John Zelle's graphics.py](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html), I want the `GraphWin` to close right after the `Circle` object has reached the edge of the window and is out of sight.

Following code creates a circle and moves it:

```
win = GraphWin("My Circle", 100, 100)
c = Circle(Point(50,50), 10)
c.draw(win)
    for i in range(40):       
      c.move(30, 0) #speed=30
      time.sleep(1)
      #c should move until the end of the windows(100), 
win.close() # then windows of title "My Circle" should close immediately
```

Is there any way to do this instead of using `range` and counting its exact number of 'steps'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the x position of the left side of the circle against the right side of the window:

```
from graphics import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 300, 300

RADIUS = 10

SPEED = 30

win = GraphWin("My Circle", WIDTH, HEIGHT)

c = Circle(Point(50, 50), RADIUS)

c.draw(win)

while c.getCenter().x - RADIUS < WIDTH:
    c.move(SPEED, 0)
    time.sleep(1)

win.close() # then windows of title "My Circle" should close immediately
```

In a speedier loop, we might move `RADIUS` to the other side of the equation and make a new constant of `WIDTH + RADIUS`.

> If it was an Image object, how would you suggest to get the leftmost
>   position of the object to compare it to the width of the window?

An `Image` object would work similarly, using it's anchor, instead of center, and using its width instead of its radius:

```
from graphics import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 300, 300

SPEED = 30

win = GraphWin("My Image", WIDTH, HEIGHT)

image = Image(Point(50, 50), "file.gif")

image.draw(win)

image_half_width = image.getWidth() / 2

while image.getAnchor().x - image_half_width < WIDTH:
    image.move(SPEED, 0)
    time.sleep(1)

win.close() # the window of title "My Image" should close immediately
```

Comment: can you explain in word form what do this line of code do? `while c.getCenter().x - RADIUS < WIDTH:`

Comment: @KimSuYu, in word form, "while the left edge of the circle (circle's center x position less the circle's radius) is to the left of the window's right edge (WIDTH), do the following:",  where "the following" is "move the circle to the right by SPEED units, then sleep one second before going on."

Comment: then assuming that an `Image` object is used rather than a  `Circle` object. will `getAnchor()` work the same way as `getCenter()`? If it was an `Image` object, how would you suggest to get the leftmost position of the object to compare it to the width of the window?

Comment: @KimSuYu, I've augmented my answer with an Image object implementation.